# How to make StaticArrayDatabase from two connections in ELKI?

Tags: java, elki

I have to connection, for two different dataset. And then, i put it into two db.

```
DatabaseConnection dbc1 = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(doubles);
DatabaseConnection dbc2 = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(secondDoubles);

Database db = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc1);
Database db1 = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc2);
```

Then do some stuff with each db, but think this is not good way, but how to join database without mixing my arrays?
i tried to solve problem, in different ways but ELKI's documentation is too complicated. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Get the [source code of `ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection`](https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/master/elki-input/src/main/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/datasource/ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection.java) and modify it as needed. The `MultipleObjectsBundle` is fairly basic (to make it easy to interface), and so is the `DatabaseConnection` interface. So you can easily plug in a custom data source (e.g. the concatenation of two arrays).

The cost of simply copying both arrays into one will only be marginally higher, usually, if you do *not* do a *deep* copy.